# spring boot basic authentication not work

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new for spring boot and I tried to develop api with basic authentication  .BUT I always gets
"status:401 Unauthorized".

*In pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

*In application.properties

```
       management.security.enabled= false
       spring.security.user.name = username
       spring.security.user.password=123456
```

Comment: Can you add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` in `application.properties` and comeback with generated logs to understand more about the problem?

Comment: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied

Comment: at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
 at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:239) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
 at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:208) ~[spring-security-core-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]

Comment: And what you are trying to access? Own controller or actuator?

Comment: own controller . i tried to call post method

Answer (score 0):

instead of set up security cofiguration in properties file, you can create a java class like this : it work well

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicatiponSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    public ApplicatiponSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder p) {
        this.passwordEncoder = p;
    //provide to encode password, without it , it don't work
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    protected  UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails s = User.builder()
                .username("username")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("123456"))
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
                    s
                );
    }
}
```